# html codes(blogger) pin it button

Tags: html, blogger, blogspot

I want to make 'pin it' button on my photos like these ones http://freefashionorgasm.blogspot.com/ and like button (center) on my blog, but how? please help me, xo

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.post-body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to your template.

Or, if you don't want your posts' text to be centered be default, add instead

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and then, in your posts, wrap your like button with a div with `class="center"`, like this:

```
<div class="center">
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 21px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://freefashionorgasm.blogspot.com/2012/08/blog-post_9995.html&send=false&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=90&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=21" allowtransparency="true">
</div>
```